# Using PHP to create a summary table of different TAXs for an order

Tags: php, mysql, system

I have an order system that uses `PHP` and `MySQL`. When creating an order some line items have different `TAX` rates. It would be great if at the end of the order, instead of just a row that totals the TAX, I would like to somehow summarise the TAX information and display the % rate with its total.

For example, an SQL order could look like this:

```
QTY  CODE       DESCRIPTION    UNIT    TAX%  TAX     TOTAL
1    Bulb       Light bulb     1.00    20    0.20    1.20
1    Plug       13A Plug       2.00    15    0.30    2.30
3    Cable      Cable /m       0.50    20    0.30    1.80
1    Delivery   Delivery       5.00    0     0.00    5.00
```

... which would be rendered on the page using the following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order) {
  $totalNet =+ $row['QTY'] * $row['UNIT'];
  $totalTax =+ $row['TAX'];
  $total =+ $row['TOTAL']'

  echo "<tr><td>".$row['QTY']."</td></tr>
  etc..
}
echo "Order Net: ".$totalNet;
echo "Order TAX: ".$totalTax;
echo "Order Total: ".$total;
```

... and at the end of the order, it would be great to show a summary of taxes, like so:

```
Vat at    Total
20%       0.50
15%       0.30
0%        0.00
```

My question is how to build this. I was thinking along the lines of `IF` statements but I'm sure there is a more logical way. Do you create a variable for each TAX%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an associative array keyed off the tax rate.

```
$taxes = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($order) {
  $totalNet =+ $row['QTY'] * $row['UNIT'];
  $totalTax =+ $row['TAX'];
  $total =+ $row['TOTAL']';
  if (isset($taxes[$row['TAX_RATE']])) {
    $taxes[$row['TAX_RATE']] += $ROW['TAX'];
  } else {
    $taxes[$row['TAX_RATE']] = $ROW['TAX'];
  }

  echo "<tr><td>".$row['QTY']."</td></tr>
  etc..
}

foreach ($taxes as $rate => $tax_rate_total) {
  echo "<tr><td>$rate%</td><td>$tax_rate_total</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, ive not played with foreach statements but after a quick read into them and arrays makes perfect sense. Thank you for answering my question!